# Не показываются иконки svg в HTML

Tags: html, html5, svg, frontend

Подскажите как корректно задавать размеры иконкам svg? В моем коде у меня есть 2 элемента svg: исходный и ссылающийся. Я задал размеры и вьюбокс в исходном, но после того как я задаю размеры, изображение вообще пропадает. Я примерно понял суть проблемы, но как ее решить?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class='logo'>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <use width='40px' height='60px' xlink:href='#logo'></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </header>
    <svg width='40px' height='60px' viewBox='200 50 600 550'>
        <path id='logo' d='M 200 400 L 400 50 L 600 400 L 500 400 L 400 50 L 500 400 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 400 50 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 200 400 ' stroke='blue' fill='transparent'></path>
    </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Задайте viewBox тому элементу, в котором Вы используете тег use, таким образом Вы задаете ему область, по которой обрезается то, что видно на этой картинке, а второе изображение можно вообще скрыть...

```html
<svg viewBox='200 50 600 550'>
    <use xlink:href='#logo'></use>
</svg>
<svg style="display:none">
    <path id='logo' d='M 200 400 L 400 50 L 600 400 L 500 400 L 400 50 L 500 400 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 400 50 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 200 400 ' stroke='blue' fill='transparent'></path>
</svg>
```